# LEFT JOINs are not mapping in EFCore 6

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have the following query in an SP. When it gets executed 3 records should be returned. However, EF returns only the 1st record 3 times. Please point out the issue here. Thank you.

```
SELECT que.QuestionId, que.Question, que.QuestionType, que.IsMandatoryQuestion, que.[File],
       que.QuesVI, ans.AnswerId, ans.AnswerLabel, ans.AnsLblVI
FROM Questions AS que
  LEFT JOIN DefinedAnswers As ans ON que.QuestionId = ans.QuestionId
WHERE que.SectionId = 5
ORDER BY que.Sequence, ans.Sequence
```

[image]

When this gets executed via EFCore (V6.0) on a .NET6 web API project a different result appears.

[image]

Please can someone show how to fix this issue?

NOTE:
The full SP code is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[sp_GetQuestionsAnswers]
  @SectionId INT
  AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
 SELECT que.QuestionId, que.Question, que.QuestionType, que.IsMandatoryQuestion, que.[File], que.QuesVI,
 ans.AnswerId, ans.AnswerLabel, ans.AnsLblVI
 FROM Questions AS que
 LEFT JOIN DefinedAnswers As ans ON que.QuestionId = ans.QuestionId
 WHERE que.SectionId = @SectionId
 ORDER BY que.Sequence , ans.Sequence
 END
GO
```

Mapping model:

```
public partial class QuestionAnswers
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int? AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public byte QuestionType { get; set; }
    public bool IsMandatoryQuestion { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
    public byte QuesVi { get; set; }

    public string AnswerLabel { get; set; }
    public byte? AnsLblVi { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing your SP call with the actual query - `.FromSqlRaw("Query").ToList()`. If not, can you try and see what's the result?

Comment: @cdrrr hi, I did but I got the same result. But the same query gives the correct result when I execute it in the SQL server management studio.

Comment: Can you also share the full SP code and your mapping model?

Comment: I have updated the question with the requested info. Thank you for your time spent.

Comment: `[Key]` attribute on `QuestionId` is the problem. You are telling EF that the column `QuestionId` is unique in the result set, while in reality it isn't. Consider mapping `QuestionAnswers` as keyless entity.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi, tried that. The issue persists.

Comment: Or map `QuestionId, AnswerId` as a composite key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, the order of the columns returned by the query don't match the same order in your mapping model. Everything including order, names, types should align. I'd first do that.

Second - I have no idea how you have defined your `dbSet` but I would do it like this: `modelBuilder.Entity<YourType>().HasNoKey().ToFunction("[dbo].[YourStoredProcedureName]").Metadata.SetIsTableExcludedFromMigrations(true);`. This basically tells `EF Core` that you want to execute a query against a `SQL` entity that doesn't have a `PK` and also exclude it from migrations (aka creating the table).

Third - I would use `.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC [dbo].[YourStoredProcedureName] @param= {param}").ToListAsync();` rather than `FromSqlRaw` as it prevents SQL injection, it's more readable and handles parameterization correctly.

Comment: This is perfect. The second instruction did the trick. Thank you very much.